# Catching SyntaxError from ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I have the following code to evaluate some configuration values stored in a file:

```
from ast import literal_eval

for key, value in dict_read_from_file.items():
    try:
        cfg[key] = literal_eval(value)
    except ValueError:
        cfg[key] = value
```

However, with certain inputs `literal_eval` raises a `SyntaxError`, rather than a `ValueError`:

```
>>> literal_eval('asdf')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x000001A065B69AE0>

>>> literal_eval('123 4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
File "ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
File "<unknown>", line 1
    123 4
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But Python doesn't seem to let me catch the `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> try:
...     literal_eval('123 4')
... except ValueError | SyntaxError:
...     print("Fixing")
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

How do I catch and properly handle this `SyntaxError`?

Comment: Have you tried just `except SyntaxError:`?

Comment: why not `except (ValueError, SyntaxError):`

Comment: @enke Thanks, that fixes the issue. I'm going to try to find where I saw the multpile-exception syntax that I used in the question so I know not to follow tips from that website any more. I'm surprised the `|` didn't raise a different error though (like its own `SyntaxError` or a `TypeError` in the `__or__` method for instance).